# How to count the number of elements by group in R?

Tags: r, statistics

i have this data frame, I want to count the frequency (number) of each unique value in a column.

```
userID  bookmarkID  tagID   value
228         1   1   0.0005
255         1   1   0.0007
5           2   1   0.0068
66          2   1   0.0008
99          2   1   0.0006
206         2   1   0.0006
3           3   1   -0.0007
5           3   1   0.0633
7           3   1   -0.0012
```

For example，the column bookmarkID, I want to get two vectors: one is the unique values [1,2,3], the other is the corresponding count: [2,4,3]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `table` and `unique`. Consider your data.frame is `df`,

```
> table(df$bookmarkID)
  1 2 3 
  2 4 3 
> unique(df$bookmarkID)
  [1] 1 2 3
```